# how to send multiple sets of different sizes to a matlab function?

Tags: matlab, parameters, matrix, arguments, argument-passing

I have a matrix in which every row has a different size, extra places are padded by zeros. This matrix depends on some input arguments and so has a dynamic and not fixed number of rows and sizes.

```
for e.g.
1 2 4 5 0
1 3 0 0 0
1 2 3 4 5
```

How do I create and send n sets of different sizes (one set from every row) to another function e.g. cartprod http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5475-cartprod-cartesian-product-of-multiple-sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want any zeros in the input vectors of `cartprod`, you can use this:

```
CellArrayWithoutZeros = cellfun(@(x) x(find(x)), num2cell(Matrix, 2), 'UniformOutput', false);

CartProdResultMatrix = cartprod(CellArrayWithoutZeros{:});
```

**Edit:** If you want to cut off only the leading zeros (on the right side of any non-zero elements) of the input vectors of `cartprod`:

```
CellArrayWithoutLeadingZeros = cellfun(@(x) x(1:find(x, 1, 'last')), num2cell(Matrix, 2), 'UniformOutput', false);

CartProdResultMatrix = cartprod(CellArrayWithoutLeadingZeros{:});
```